# CSS Even&odd affect the thead

Tags: css, css-tables

I use `even` & `odd` CSS rule for a table but that's also the changing <thead>.

```
thead {background-color: #999;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #fff}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #C8C8C8}
```

The result is that my <thead> is `#C8C8C8` and not `#999`.

So my question is, is that possible to use even & odd without that's affect the <thead>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `tbody` to you selector so that the rule only applies to tr:s within your tbody:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background: #fff}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #C8C8C8}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use `tbody` selector:

```
thead{background-color: #999;}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background: #fff}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #C8C8C8}
```

Because you are using `<tbody>` elements on your `<table>`, right? If don't, you should use it :)